# Monitoring & Detecting Exceptions in Applications using Cloud Monitoring

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

I am new to GCP and come from an Azure background. Is there an equivalent of "Azure Application Insights" on the GCP side for Monitoring Applications?

Let me explain my use case more clearly with an example: If I have a .NET based web application running on a Windows VM on GCP can Google Cloud Monitoring help detect Exceptions raised by the running application and send out alerts.

Any pointers/links to further explore this type of monitoring capability would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Cloud Monitoring will provide you with many statisctics - most probably with what you need. And if there aren't any metrics to suit you need you may create ones [based on the logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics) collected from the VM.

By default there is a number of logs being ingested but if you want to have full range and experiment with various ones you may want to [install a monitoring agent](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/agent/installation#agent-install-windows). Go through the documentation and have a look.

You can then use the metrics to create charts and have a live view on a number of things such as cpu utilisation, disk IO/s, dropped/sent/received packets etc. Here's the [Cloud Monitoring documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/quickstart-lamp).

And finally - you can [create alerts](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts/using-alerting-ui) based on the metrics (set thresholds, time periods etc). They can be simple e-mail alerts for example but [they can be sent via pub-sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/monitoring) and trigger some functions or apps too.

Since you're new to GCP it's a lot of reading ahead of you but you will easily find documentation for most of GCP's services.

If you provide more details I can update my answer and give you more precise answer.